# How to remove these icons from Settings app?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, microsoft-edge, default-settings

I am primarily a Linux user, but currently I'm configuring a laptop with preinstalled Windows 10 and need to tweak several things.

When I open the Settings app, three icons referring to logging to OneDrive, setting "recommended" Internet settings (that is, setting MS Edge as default browser) and Windows Update appear on top of the app window (see the below screenshot - sorry it's not in English). I would like to remove at least the OneDrive and Internet icons (the ones with blue dots). I have disabled OneDrive via the GPO according to info I found on the web, so clicking on that icon does not do anything, but clicking on the Internet icon asks me if I want to reset MS Edge as a default browser (which I don't, I have set default browser to Firefox and it has to stay so).

I know it is possible to remove these icons as the computer that I'm using at work - also with Win 10 Pro (installed from our corporate Windows image, so I don't know the details) - does not have any icons there. However, I can't find any information how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer related to browser settings.

1. Go to Settings -> Apps -> Default apps -> Recommended browser settings.
2. Disable "Set Microsoft Edge as your default browser and pin it to your desktop and taskbar"

[image]

Comment: I don't have any checkboxes there. Under "Get more info" link, there's directly the "Confirm" button.

Comment: @raj Which version and build of Windows 10 are you setting up?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro 21H2, build 19044.1826. The version information screen also mentions something called "Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0"

Comment: [Edit] your question instead of submitting relevant information necessary to absolutely answer your question